# flip flop counter design

Tags: flipflop

I need to design a counter count from 0-9 using a 4 bit counter(JK,T,SR and D flip flop). I know the concept of using an excitation table, draw the K-map for each input. But for this case, since this is 4 bit I need to input numbers from 0-15 and 10-15 is not use. So will it work by putting transition 10->0,11->0,12->0,13->0,14->0 and 15->0? since the loop only counting from 0 to 9, it will never reach 10 and there is no way to leave the table 10-15 as blank, some sort like make it redundant?

Comment: Logically it could not exceed 9, in reality glitches etc can easily create an illegal state, so it is good design practice to ensure all unused states go to a valid one.

Comment: ... or eventually end up at a valid one, so counting 11->12->13->14->15->0 would be permissible, although not recovering as fast as all illegals->0, and infinitely better than getting 'stuck' in an illegal state like 14->14->14 ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I haven't considered the case for glitches

Comment: @chuackt I don't know if the 'glitch' advice is useful. It depends on the application for it. I can be equally bad to skip one count and recover as it is to skip 5 and then recover, if the application requires that there are no mistakes at all (I'm thinking about certain life-critical medical devices.) Plus, if this is going into space then designs that statistically work for a decade before a glitch might statistically work for only a week there (depending on what radiation it is sensitive to, and how so.) What's the reason for dealing with illegal states here? I'm curious.